# How to clear the cookies for foursquare in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I am using foursquare in my application but I can't to sign-out from the foursquare in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to `remove` `foursquare` `cookie` from app

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
   NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
   NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"foursquare"];
   if(domainRange.length > 0)
   {
       [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this wherever you want to just like

```
   NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if ([cookie.name isEqualToString:@"FourSquare"]) {//its temprory name for your understanding
       [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    };

}
```